# Is it Conventional to put libraries and include into standard directories like /usr/lib/ after installing a package with Make

Tags: software-installation, libraries

After installing mesa-12.0.0, I have the library and header files in

> ~/Downloads/mesa-12.0.0/lib
>   ~/Downloads/mesa-12.0.0/include

Is it better to simply add the path to **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** or should I put them into more standard paths such as /usr/lib. What is the best way to put organize the package or both are ok ?

Thanks.

Comment: What Operating System+

Answer (score 4):

You should not put in `/usr/lib`: don't mix OS stuff with locally installed stuff.

You can put them in `/usr/local/`, this is a shadow of `/`. It has `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/include` etc. You should also look into `stow` it will help you manage your local packages (Keep them separate from each other. While putting them all together.)

Or you can keep them in your home directory: `stow` can, optionally, help here also.

It is up to you, if you install globally (`/usr/local/`) or in user directory. Both can be shared with others. But by putting in `/usr/local`, they are automatically shared. And you need admin (root or …) access to install.

Comment: Even `/usr/local` may be out of bounds if you are on a system where the package manager installs software there (as on some BSDs).  There's nothing stopping a local administrator from using `/opt` or some other top-level directory for locally managed software though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I did not know that package managers install to there (how rude of them, did they not learn from earlier error?: When `/usr` became a system directory.). I use `/opt` to install stuff that is designed to stay self contained: one dir per package.

Comment: Well, FreeBSD and OpenBSD does (NetBSD uses `/usr/pkg`). And it makes sense. Packages are not part of the base system, so they are classified as "local software" since it's a local administrator that installs them.